# Unique buildConfigField for all flavors with dimensions

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, android-flavors, android-flavordimension

I has two flavor dimensions: `brand` and `version`, my flavors config looks like:

```
flavorDimensions 'brand', 'version'

Brand1 { 
    dimension 'brand'
    ...
}

Brand2 {
    dimension 'brand'
    ...
}

Version1 {
    dimension 'version'
    ...
}

Version2 {
    dimension 'version'
    ...
}
```

And I want to have four unique `buildConfigField`-s (for example HockeyAppId) for every configurations:

- Brand1Version1
- Brand1Version2
- Brand2Version1
- Brand2Version2

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote my own plugin for that purpose: https://github.com/nikialeksey/porflavor, and now I can define such fields:

```
flavorDimensions 'brand', 'version'

productFlavors {
  Brand1 { 
    dimension 'brand'
    ...
  }
  Brand2 {
    dimension 'brand'
    ...
  }

  Version1 {
    dimension 'version'
    ...
  }
  Version2 {
    dimension 'version'
    ...
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.nikialeksey.porflavor'
porflavor {
  Brand1Version1 {
    buildConfigField "boolean", "fooFeatureEnabled", "false"
  }
  Brand2Version2 {
    buildConfigField "boolean", "fooFeatureEnabled", "true"
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

so this is pretty straight forward. You can modify per flavor or release type without any crazy effort.

If you are attempting to reuse a flavor in multiple dimensions, that is not their desired functionality. a flavor is meant to be a built compiled packaged version of the app. It's not really meant to be a generic set of parameters. So you will need a flavor for every variance such as

> flavor1 -> in dimension 1
>
> flavor1Dimension2 -> in dimension 2
>
> flavor2 -> in dimension 1
>
> flavor2Dimension2 -> in dimension 2 etc..

Here I will give an example of using dynamic

- resources
- buildconfig
- manifest placeholder
- application id

Of course there is more you can do but this should get you going with your request.

```
flavorDimensions 'default', 'secondary'

productFlavors {
    a35Demo {
        dimension 'default'
        applicationId "com.appstudio35.yourappstudio.demo"
        buildConfigField "int", "BUSINESS_ID", "1"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App Studio 35"
        buildConfigField "String", "NOTIFICATION_ICON", '"ic_launcher"'
        manifestPlaceholders = [iconPath:"@mipmap/ic_launcher", roundIconPath:"@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"]
    }
    smallville {
        dimension 'secondary'
        applicationId "com.appstudio35.yourappstudio.smallville"
        buildConfigField "int", "BUSINESS_ID", "22"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Smallville"
        buildConfigField "String", "NOTIFICATION_ICON", '"ic_launcher_smallville"'
        manifestPlaceholders = [iconPath:"@mipmap/ic_launcher_smallville", roundIconPath:"@mipmap/ic_launcher_round_smallville"]
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"https://api.dev.myurl.com"'
        shrinkResources false //remove unused resources per flavor
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", '"https://api.prod.myurl.com"'

        shrinkResources true //remove unused resources per flavor
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        //production builds
        productFlavors.a35Demo.signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseA35YourAppStudio
        productFlavors.smallville.signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseA35YourAppStudio
    }
}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks! But there is only one flavor dimension in your example - `default`. I want to add a unique `buildConfigField` for flavor described in multiple dimensions

Comment: Sorry I didn't add that because I figured that part was simple. Just change the dimension. I updated the example to show. Unless I'm misunderstanding your challenge?

Comment: Ok I get what you are asking, I updated my answer to clarify, but you are trying to use flavors in a way that they are not intended to be used in my opinion.

Comment: I wrote my own plugin for that purpose: https://github.com/nikialeksey/porflavor , and now I can configure variants for flavors with dimensions